# RelativeLayout and TextView with not working gravity

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-relativelayout

I have a simple list item layout to show a image and a title.

```
<RelativeLayout            
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/image" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/image"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/image"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Title" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

My problem is the text gravity which should be `"center-vertical"`. When I display the view bounds in the developer setting then I can see the `TextView` size is greater then the text itself but the gravity stays on top. The problem appears on my android `KitKat` device but not on `Android Froyo` for example.

Comment: Try setting the TextView height to match its parent. and leave `android:gravity="center_vertical"`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a [known issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=59368) that has already been fixed and it doesn't affect Marshmallow (I haven't tried it on Lollipop though). The (not so elegant) solution is to wrap your `TextView` in a `FrameLayout`:

```
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/image" />

  <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/image"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/image"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true">

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/title"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
      android:text="Title" />

  </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `android:gravity="center_vertical"` to  `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`

Simply use this layout,it will work

```
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:src="@drawable/image" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:text="Title" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.

<LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:gravity="center_vertical">

   <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Title" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help but i want to archive it with a RelativeLayout because i broke down my problem to the simplest one but i a have more then 8 child views in the layout.

Answer (score 0):

Check this layout code and

[image]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"           
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:text="@string/hello_world" />
            </RelativeLayout>
```